# Using CASE within a where clause - with a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a good example of a case statement inside a where clause, using a variable.  The number returned by the variable determines the result of the where clause.  My query looks like this:

```
IF          @RequestType = 99
    SELECT  @Received = count(*)
    FROM    Request r
    WHERE   request_received_date between @beginDate and @endDate
    AND     request_type_id <> 5
    ELSE IF @RequestType = 100
BEGIN
    SELECT  @Received = count(*)
    FROM    Request r
    WHERE   request_received_date between @beginDate and @endDate
END
    ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT  @Received = count(*)
    FROM    Request r
    WHERE   request_received_date between @beginDate and @endDate
    AND     request_type_id = 
            (CASE WHEN @RequestType = 1 THEN (1)
            WHEN @RequestType = 2 THEN (2)
            WHEN @RequestType = 3 THEN (3)
            WHEN @RequestType = 4 THEN (4)
            WHEN @RequestType = 5 THEN (5)
            END)
END
```

So as you can see, there are 7 options - the customer wants to be flexible with the amount of data they see in the report.  This looks cumbersome to me but I can't think of any other way to do this.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of SQL as one of the tags.

Comment: Whats the point of that case statement ? why not just: `request_type_id = @RequestType`

Answer (score 0):

you could probably simplify the query to...

```
SELECT
      count(*) as Received
   FROM
      ( select 3 as RqType,
               '2015-10-01' as beginDate, 
               '2015-10-20' as endDate) as PV,
      Request r
   WHERE   
          request_received_date between PV.beginDate and PV.endDate
      AND case when PV.RqType = 100  then 1=1
               when PV.RqType = 99   then r.request_type_id <> 5
               when PV.RqType <= 6   then PV.RqType = r.request_type_id 
          end
```

The LAST case/when component matches on the request type is getting the values under 6 to match that of the request type.  If you have negatives, then just adjust that accordingly.

I revised the query to have a prequery "PV" indicating the parameter values you are looking for, so they can just be changed to whatever request type and date-range as you need.  This should be good for SQL-Server, and probably other SQL engines too.  By just doing a query of hard values with no "FROM", it essentially creates a result set of a single record with those values of which you can then use for the rest of the query.  Any by being a single record, no issue for any Cartesian joins.

Comment: I'm slapping my forehead at this very moment.  Thanks for the nudge ;)

Comment: @Ringl, glad you have not flattened the forehead yet :)... Also, if it works, make sure to mark as solved so others know too... Also check-out HELP -> TOUR for site etiquette.  Welcome to the forum.

Comment: Is this mysql syntax?  How does the sql server version look?

Comment: @Ringl, you had generically "sql" for the tag and not specific of MySQL, or SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.  I was just following your premise of variables.  I have revised the query and it should work for you.

Comment: Yes I know, now I'm hanging my head in shame.  I do apologize.G its been an emotional few days. I feel like Sarah Bernhardt.

Comment: If it worked, check as marked so others know it is solved... then check HELP -> TOUR for other site etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually no need for CASE WHEN in WHERE clauses, as you have AND and OR. Your queries translate to:

```
select @Received = count(*)
from request
where request_received_date between @beginDate and @endDate
and 
(
  @RequestType = 100
    or
  (@RequestType = 99 and request_type_id <> 5)
    or
  (@RequestType = request_type_id and request_type_id in (1,2,3,4,5))
);
```